# list all files having a git attribute set

Tags: git, gitattributes

`git check-attr` allows me to check if an attribute is set in `.gitattributes` for a specific set of files. 
e.g:

```
# git check-attr myAttr -- org/example/file1 org/example/file2
org/example/file1: myAttr: set
org/example/file2: myAttr: unspecified
```

Is there an easy way to list all files having `myAttr` set, including all wildcard matches?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could set as an argument the list with all the files in your repository using `git ls-files`, like this:

```
git check-attr myAttr `git ls-files`
```

If your repository has too many files you might the following error:

> -bash: /usr/bin/git: Argument list too long

which you can overcome with [xargs](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?xargs):

```
git ls-files | xargs git check-attr myAttr
```

Finally, if you have too many files you will probably want to filter out the ones where you didn't specify the argument, to make the output more readable:

```
git ls-files | xargs git check-attr myAttr | grep -v 'unspecified$'
```

With grep, you could apply more filters to this output in order to match just the files that you want.

Comment: This solution works well and sufficiently fast for smaller repositories. But I think for larger projects `git check-attr` should be enhanced to list all files having an attribute set.

Answer (score 10):

The other posts weren't working well for me, but I got there:

```
git ls-files | git check-attr -a --stdin
```

"Check every file in git and print all filters" one liner.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get only the list of files, and use NUL character for being resilient for filenames or attributes that contain `\n` or `:`, you can do:

For the list of file that have the attribute "merge=union":

```
git ls-files -z | git check-attr --stdin -z merge | sed -z -n -f script.sed
```

With script.sed:

```
             # read filename
x            # save filename in temporary space
n            # read attribute name and discard it
n            # read attribute name
s/^union$//  # check if the value of the attribute match
t print      # in that case goto print
b            # otherwise goto the end
:print
x            # restore filename from temporary space
p            # print filename
             # start again
```

The same thing with the sed script inlined (i.e. using `-e` instead of `-f`, ignoring comments and replacing newlines with semicolons):

```
git ls-files -z | git check-attr --stdin -z merge | sed -zne 'x;n;n;s/^union$//;t print;b;:print;x;p'
```

PS: The result separates filenames using NUL character, use `| xargs --null printf "%s\n"` in order to print them in a human readable way.